# Get one field with $sth->execute()

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT personid FROM accountpersonmap WHERE accountid = :accountid; ";
 $array = array(
    'accountid' => $eachRow['accountid']
 );
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute(array(':personid' => $personid))
 echo $personid;
```

I just want the personid please? 
i googled but not finding what i am looking for.

thanks

Comment: check this `print_r($sth)` and tell us the result

Comment: i tried the fetch_column and tried out examples i found in the rest of this code written by some-one else but not fining what i am looking for

Comment: with print_r($sth) I get: [queryString] => SELECT personid FROM accountpersonmap WHERE accountid = :accountid;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that should work

```
$sql = "SELECT personid FROM accountpersonmap WHERE accountid = :accountid ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':accountid' => $eachRow['accountid']));
$personid = $sth->fetchColumn();
echo $personid;
```

Comment: i tried this but not getting anything :)

Comment: code edited doesn't return anything ?

Comment: thanks man! :) working now, me did something wrong, my bad , sorry

Answer (score 0):

You need no google but tutorial. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

To get the value, you have to fetch it.

Also, judging by this variable, `$eachRow['accountid']`, it seems you need to use JOIN in your other query, instead of running this one in a loop.

Update.

As I told above, you need a **tutorial**.
Not just a cargo cult example, but a tutorial to learn and comprehend how to work with PDO. How to get an error from PDO for example. As at closer look there is a silly typo in your code:

```
 WHERE accountid = :accountid;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but

```
 $sth->execute(array(':personid' => $personid))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And PDO should have reported it if configured properly.

Comment: i have an outside loop but dont need to join anything. the $eachRow['accountid'] contains the accountid i want, but now need to get the personid that belongs to the accountid :)

Comment: Yes. that's what JOIN is for. Exactly

Comment: here is my loop: foreach ($paramData['arrayparams'] as $key => $eachRow) {   ///my code  } and array params:
'arrayparams' => array(
  array('accountid' => 128887,
       'title' => 'you can call me miss update',
              'firstname' => 'firstname update',
       'lastname' => 'lastname update' }

Comment: Just rewrite it to join and get rid of this nested query